# Agrupar y seleccionar el registro con fecha más reciente MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, select, group-by

Tengo un gran problema en  MySQL, se ve que es algo sencillo, pero para mi poca experiencia no logro hacer lo siguiente, de la tabla que pongo a continuación necesito agrupar mediante una Query los idEmpleado y obtener solo un registro por cada idEmpleado, el cual debe ser el que tenga la fecha más reciente. Necesito obtener toda la fila y no solo la fecha o el id. Es posible hacer eso?

[image: Es mi tabla actual]

Comment: No, necesito que por cada idEmpleado busque la que tenga fecha mayor y ese registro se mueste

Comment: @RubenHernandez por favor publica tu comentario como respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: si la respuesta dada ha solucionado tu problema, por favor [acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Si en efecto lo que preguntas es posible, podría ser algo como esto;

```
SELECT DISTINCT(idEmpleado),FechaMovimiento,Area 
FROM bd_secjo.tblmovimientos
GROUP BY idEmpleado,FechaMovimiento,Area
ORDER BY FechaMovimiento
```

> Nota que estoy haciendo seleccion de los campos para posteriormente
>   agrupar o limitar a 1 registro por idempleado, ahora bien no necesitas
>   agrupar puedes hacer simplemente un `DISTINCT` al campo idEmpleado

```
SELECT DISTINCT(idEmpleado),FechaMovimiento,Area 
FROM bd_secjo.tblmovimientos
ORDER BY FechaMovimiento DESC
```

Comment: Esta sin duda es la mejor opción, ya que la sub consulta requiere mucha mas recursos